# Extract variable from SSIS package deployed in SQL Server Integration Service Catalog

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a task to extract out a specific variable from all the projects deployed in SQL Server Integration Service Catalog. I have the code to extract out the variable with the XML code from dtsx file in the file system. But, how do i get the XML code from Integration Service Catalog?

I did some research and found out that we can extract the package to an ispac file and then extract it out to get the dtsx package. Is there any other way to achieve this?

```
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[get_project] @folder_name = @environmentFolder,  @project_name = @project
```

Comment: There is a table called [SSISDB].[internal].[object_parameters] and column object_name is the name of the package and parameter_name contains the name of the parameter and column design_default_value contains value of the parameter during the design but if join this data with [SSISDB].[internal].[execution_parameter_values] you will get the value of the parameters during runtime.  In this I dont think you need to parse every thing you need about the package variables are stored in tables.

Comment: @akhilavangala - I can get the project parameters and the package parameters from [SSISDB].[internal].[object_parameters]. But the package variables are not present in this table. I would like to extract out the variables.